# Where are Minecraft Mods saved by default on a Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos, minecraft-mods

I am trying to delete a crashing game mod but I cant find my minecraft folder anywhere in my mac!
Where is it???

Comment: If you have installed mods, you should know where you put them.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally in `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft` (where `~` means your home directory).

The Library folder is normally hidden in recent versions of macOS so you won't see this in Finder. One way to view it is to use the 'Go' menu item in Finder and press Alt (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) which will add Library to the list of folders.

Comment: Does have Mac launcher same profile editor as standard launcher? Then it could be easier way to go to profile editor and click "open folder"?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know anything about Minecraft itself, just where to find it